# Count Number of UnViewed Posts

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a db structure like:

### posts

```
id
title
content
```

### users

```
id
....
```

### post_reads

```
post_id
user_id
```

How can I count the number of posts for which a particular user with an id say, `x` does not have a read record.

My SQL query currently looks like:

```
SELECT COUNT(posts.id) AS c
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `post_reads` ON (`posts`.`id` = `post_reads`.`post_id`)
LEFT JOIN `users` ON (post_reads.user_id = `users`.`id` AND post_reads.user_id = x)
WHERE users.id IS NULL
AND post_reads.user_id IS NULL
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, although I'm not sure what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should to the trick

```
SELECT COUNT(posts.id) AS c
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_reads ON posts.id = post_reads.post_id AND post_reads.user_id = x
LEFT JOIN users ON post_reads.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.id IS NULL
```

Note that if you're not interested in doing anything with table users you can shorten this query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(posts.id) AS c
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN post_reads ON posts.id = post_reads.post_id AND post_reads.user_id = x
WHERE post_reads.user_id IS NULL
```

The first join you were doing is really an inner join, because it will never 'misfire'.

The second join will sometimes misfire, because you have the **extra** condition in there.
Therefore using the `post_reads.some_id is null` will never be true.
In order for that to work you'd have to repeat the `AND post_reads.user_id = x` in that join condition as well, but putting it in twice is silly and not needed, once will do.

PS don't forget to replace the 'x' with something more useful :-)

Comment: Won't the INNER JOIN exclude any posts that haven't yet been read by **any** users? I assume no `post_reads` record will exist in that case.

Comment: @djacobson, depending on your application no/yes/maybe, you know best, I doubt that though because otherwise you'd be getting results :_) and you wouldn't be asking this question, but please experiment and see the difference.

Comment: @Johan Um, I'm not the person who asked the question, and let me rephrase my comment: There's a problem with this solution, which is that the INNER JOIN will exclude posts that haven't been read by any users, except in the highly-unlikely case that the OP's schema includes "dummy" `post_reads` records for unread posts.

Comment: @djacobson, sorry confused you with the OP, @Zahymaka, you guys look so alike it's uncanny.

Comment: Well, I actually got it working by moving the extra condition to the first join, i.e.: `...LEFT JOIN post_reads ON (posts.id = post_reads.post_id AND post_reads.user_id = x)` and then I queried for users.id IS NULL like your answer.

Comment: @Zahymaka, fixed answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: I'm almost sure the last join is not needed and, accordingly, the WHERE condition should be changed to either `post_reads.post_id IS NULL` or `post_reads.user_id IS NULL`. Unless someday the OP decides to filter by a user *name* (or some other attribute that is not id).

Comment: @andriy M, you're right I changed the query as a result of feedback of Zahymaka but didn't change it enough.

Comment: @Johan: Sorry for disturbing you again, but the `post_reads.id` column (in the WHERE clause) may be erroneous. Zahymaka doesn't mention it and it does seem like it's unnecessary too.

Comment: @Andriy M, post_reads doesn't seem to have an `id` field. The `where` though is necessary to limit the result to users that do not have a read record.

Comment: @Johan: Absolutely. I only meant that the column name should be different, which I can see you have already changed. Seems fine now, cheers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a few ways just using JOINS/WHERE, but they tend to miss certain cases (i.e. you can exclude posts joined to a read record for the given user, but the posts' ids will still be returned if they also join to read records for other users).

The simplest way may be something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) 
FROM posts
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM post_reads WHERE user_id = @x)
```

Also, note that I don't believe you need to surround identifiers in backticks unless they are MySQL keywords.